# Get all microposts posted by people the current user follows

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join

I'm building a twitter clone and to build the timeline I need to get all microposts posted by anyone the current user follows.

[Railstutorial.org implements it like this](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#sec%3athe_status_feed):

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope :order => 'microposts.created_at DESC'

  # Return microposts from the users being followed by the given user.
  scope :from_users_followed_by, lambda { |user| followed_by(user) }

  private

    # Return an SQL condition for users followed by the given user.
    # We include the user's own id as well.
    def self.followed_by(user)
      following_ids = %(SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
                        WHERE follower_id = :user_id)
      where("user_id IN (#{following_ids}) OR user_id = :user_id",
            { :user_id => user })
    end
end
```

But I feel like a sub-select is a bit messy, and I think I'd prefer to accomplish this via joins. Here's the SQL I want:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM   Users u
       INNER JOIN Follows f
         ON u.id = f.follower_id
       INNER JOIN Microposts m
         ON s.user_id = f.followee_id
WHERE  u.id = [current users id]
ORDER  BY m.posted_at DESC
```

How can I translate this to ActiveRecord associations?

Also, which method will generally be faster for this task – the sub-select or the join?

Comment: The way you format SQL hurts my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class User
  has_many :posts

  has_many :follower_links, :class_name => "Follow", :foreign_key => :followee_id
  has_many :followers, :through => :follower_links, :source => follower

  has_many :followee_links, :class_name => "Follow", :foreign_key => :follower_id
  has_many :followees, :through => :followee_links, :source => followee

  def followee_posts
    Post.joins("JOIN (#{followees.to_sql}) AS followees 
      ON posts.user_id = followees.id")
  end
end

class Follow
  belongs_to :followee, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :follower, :class_name => "User"
end

class Post
  belongs_to :user
end
```